# Code first 2 columns as primarykey/index

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

So I got a class called ObjectA it has many ObjectsB, the objects got a Id, to identify them but ALSO a language (enum, but it is actually saved as and INT and doesn t matter either for this case).

```
public class ObjectA
{
       public int Id {get;set;}
       public Language Language {get;set;}
       ... // and a list of objectA properties

       public virtual ICollection<ObjectB> ObjectBs {get;set;}
}

public class ObjectB
{
       public int Id {get;set;}
       public Language Language {get;set;}
       ... // and a list of objectB properties

       public ObjectA TheObjectA {get;set;}
}
```

Now I learned how to map them both as a primary key, I use fluent API for this. I know you can also use [Key] and [Column] attributes (which I don t use):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectA>().HasKey(a => new {a.Id, a.Languague})
modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectB>().HasKey(a => new {a.Id, a.Languague})
```

Now I tried a lot of stuff but I can't seem to be able to connect them with each other. Anyone has an idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9573043/861716

Comment: Are you trying to have composite primary key with ID and Language fields? Any reason for not using Key and Column attributes? Are you using EF5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the principal (`ObjectA`) in a one-to-many relationship has a composite primary key the dependent (`ObjectB`) must have a foreign key that is composed of the same number of columns as well.

I assume that the related objects A and objects B must have the same language. In that case you can make `ObjectB.Language` the first part of the foreign key. (It's part of the primary and foreign key in `ObjectB` at the same time.) If you expose the second part of the FK as property in your model, it would look like this:

(I believe you must swap `Id` and `Language` for the following to work.)

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public Languague Languague {get;set;}
    public int Id {get;set;}
    ... // and a list of objectA properties

    public virtual ICollection<ObjectB> ObjectBs {get;set;}
}

public class ObjectB
{
    public Languague Languague {get;set;}
    public int Id {get;set;}
    ... // and a list of objectB properties

    public int TheObjectAId {get;set;}
    public ObjectA TheObjectA {get;set;}
}
```

And the mapping with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectA>().HasKey(a => new { a.Languague, a.Id })
modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectB>().HasKey(b => new { b.Languague, b.Id })

modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectA>()
    .HasMany(a => a.ObjectBs)
    .WithRequired(b => b.ObjectA)
    .HasForeignKey(b => new { b.Language, b.TheObjectAId });
```

If the languages can be different introduce a separate FK property for the language:

```
    public Language TheObjectALanguage {get;set;}
    public int TheObjectAId {get;set;}
    public ObjectA TheObjectA {get;set;}
```

...and map:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectA>()
    .HasMany(a => a.ObjectBs)
    .WithRequired(b => b.ObjectA)
    .HasForeignKey(b => new { b.TheObjectALanguage, b.TheObjectAId });
```

If the relationship is optional use `WithOptional` instead of `WithRequired` and make the FK properties nullable:

```
public Language? TheObjectALanguage {get;set;}
public int? TheObjectAId {get;set;}
```

I you don't want to have FK properties in your model you can use `MapKey` with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectA>()
    .HasMany(a => a.ObjectBs)
    .WithRequired(b => b.ObjectA)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("TheObjectALanguage, TheObjectAId")); // FK columns
```